# Замостить текст в овальную область JS | CSS

Tags: javascript, css, css3

Существует ли свойство в CSS или JS, которое позволит замостить текст в овальную область?

```css
.tmp{
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 20px 10px;
    font-size: 25px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    border: 1px #f00 solid;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="tmp">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur, consequatur.</div>
```

То есть, если слова не вписываются в область, то происходил бы перенос слов.
`text-overflow: ellipsis;` не помогает.

Comment: shape-outside - если сделать с двух сторон - гемморой, на svg можно сделать с огромной поддержкой на всех устройствах но будет это статично

Comment: @MaximLensky на счет svg не посоветуете?

Comment: там статично - где поставите перенос там и будет - могу показать

Comment: это вообще геморойная задача - лучше пересмотреть

Comment: @Sevastopol' это не дубликат

Answer (score 0):

Вот:

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

:root {
  --size: auto;
  --half-size: calc(var(--size) / 2);
}

.text {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  position: relative;
  width: var(--size);
  max-width: 900px;
  height: var(--size) / 2;
  padding: 50px;
  hyphens: auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 35px;
  line-height: 2;
}

.text:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #FFF;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), inset 0 0 15px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

.shape {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}

.shape__left {
  float: left;
  shape-outside: radial-gradient(var(--size) at right, transparent 50%, black 0);
}

.shape__right {
  float: right;
  shape-outside: radial-gradient(var(--size) at left, transparent 50%, black 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
  <span class="shape shape__left"></span>
  <span class="shape shape__right"></span>
  <p>Земля – чудесная планета, ее природа разнообразна. Природа нашей планеты – это совокупность каждого элемента: физических естественных и материальных. Природой можно называть только то.</p>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Поигравшись немного с font-size, текст тоже вылазит за пределы. Либо если добавить или уменьшить кол-во слов. Одним словом не вариант.

Comment: Вы сами поиграйте с текстом, добавьте пару слов или уберите или измените размер, я это не выдумал.

Comment: @Владимир можете поверить - это не возможно сделать - статически- можно - но придётся менять текст по буквам - а динамически нет

Comment: @Владимир https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/eYpzgxV вот так можно сделать а вот обернуть крутом/овалом нет

Comment: @MaximLensky из ответов я понял, то без небольшой самописной формулы на JS тут не решить задачу.

Comment: @Владимир если сделаешь и покажешь как - будет 100% круто

Answer (score 0):

А ещё можно так

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@100;400&display=swap');
.circle {
  height: 25vw;
  width: 50vw;
  shape-outside: ellipse();
  clip-path: ellipse();
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  pad
}

.content {
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  <div class="content">
    Приветики! Как оно?
  </div>
</div>
```

И можно даже сделать обтекание!

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@100;400&display=swap');
body {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.circle {
  float: left;
  height: 25vw;
  width: 50vw;
  shape-outside: ellipse();
  clip-path: ellipse();
  background: red;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.content {
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 26px;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  <div class="content">
    Приветики! Как оно?
  </div>
</div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi nisi cupiditate sunt quis sapiente, placeat dignissimos non eligendi odio impedit. Beatae alias quae eveniet quaerat saepe distinctio eius excepturi voluptas.</p>
```

Comment: внутри надо а не снаружи

Answer (score -3):

Свойство `text-overflow: ellipsis;` работает для текста, а Вы применяете его к блоку. Кроме того, это свойство работает только в том случае, когда у родительского блока `overflow` установлен в `auto, scroll или hidden`

Я немного поправил Ваш пример. Посмотрите)

```css
.tmp{
    width: 300px;
    height: auto;
    padding: 20px 10px;
    font-size: 25px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    border: 1px #f00 solid;
    overflow: auto;
    text-align: center;
    
    p {
text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="tmp"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur, consequatur.</p></div>
```

Comment: text-overflow не работает здесь - можете удалить и ни какой разницы не  будет

Comment: Абсолютно никакой разницы